# Phonegap code as a web app

Tags: cordova, web-applications, mobile, porting

I am thinking of re-using my phonegap html, css and js code as a web app.
I would be going through and removing any mobile only functionalities.

The purpose is to have a web app which offers some of the mobile apps functionality, I use very little mobile device features currently. But I am guessing maintaining with each release of my mobile app code will be troublesome.

Any of you guys tried this before ? Any tips ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a responsive design your phonegap code should run on almost any device. It's important to know what it is running on (both device and OS) so you can respond accordingly. I build a `window.deviceInfo` object up front with the following information:

- `window.deviceInfo.type`: `handheld`, `tablet`, `desktop`
- `window.deviceInfo.brand`: `ios`, `android`, `microsoft`, `webos`, `blackberry`
- `window.deviceInfo.mode`: `browser`, `standalone`, `webview`
- `window.deviceInfo.mobile`: `true`, `false`
- `window.deviceInfo.phonegap`: `true`, `false`

I use a single container `<div>` called `viewport` to create my responsive container and size it based on the device it's on.

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

This is the initialization code to set everything up:

```js
initializeEnvironment();
initializeDimensions();
initializePhoneGap( function () {
   //start app  
} );
```

First I set up `window.deviceInfo`.

```js
function initializeEnvironment() {
    //window.deviceInfo.type: handheld, tablet, desktop
    //window.deviceInfo.brand: ios, android, microsoft, webos, blackberry
    //window.deviceInfo.mode: browser, standalone, webview
    //window.deviceInfo.mobile: true, false 
    //window.deviceInfo.phonegap: true, false 

    var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    window.deviceInfo = {};

    if ( /ipad/.test( userAgent ) || ( /android/.test( userAgent ) && !/mobile/.test( userAgent ) ) ) {
        window.deviceInfo.type = 'tablet';
    } else if ( /iphone|ipod|webos|blackberry|android/.test( userAgent ) ) {
        window.deviceInfo.type = 'handheld';
    } else {
        window.deviceInfo.type = 'desktop';
    };

    if ( /iphone|ipod|ipad/.test( userAgent ) ) {
        var safari = /safari/.test( userAgent );
        window.deviceInfo.brand = 'ios';
        if ( window.navigator.standalone ) {
            window.deviceInfo.mode = 'standalone';
        } else if ( safari ) {
            window.deviceInfo.mode = 'browser';
        } else if ( !safari ) {
            window.deviceInfo.mode = 'webview';
        };
    } else if ( /android/.test( userAgent ) ) {
        window.deviceInfo.brand = 'android';
        window.deviceInfo.mode = 'browser';
    } else if ( /webos/.test( userAgent ) ) {
        window.deviceInfo.brand = 'webos';
        window.deviceInfo.mode = 'browser';
    } else if ( /blackberry/.test( userAgent ) ) {
        window.deviceInfo.brand = 'blackberry';
        window.deviceInfo.mode = 'browser';
    } else {
        window.deviceInfo.brand = 'unknown';
        window.deviceInfo.mode = 'browser';
    };
    window.deviceInfo.mobile = ( window.deviceInfo.type == 'handheld' || window.deviceInfo.type == 'tablet' );
};
```

Then I resize the `viewport` and anything else that needs it. Mobile devices use `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` to take up the full screen.

```js
function initializeDimensions() {
    var viewport = document.getElementById( 'viewport' );
    if ( window.deviceInfo.mobile ) {
        viewport.style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px';
        viewport.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
    } else {
        //requirements for your desktop layout may be different than full screen
        viewport.style.width = '300px';
        viewport.style.height = '300px';
    };
    //set individual ui element sizes here
};
```

Finally, I use `window.device` (note this is not the same as the `deviceInfo` object I create) to verify if phonegap is available and ready. Instead of relying on the finicky `deviceready` event, I poll that object when my code is running on a device that *should* be running phonegap. When the `initializePhoneGap()` callback is called, the app is ready to start.

Throughout the app, I wrap phonegap features in `if( window.deviceInfo.phonegap ) {}`.

```js
function initializePhoneGap( complete ) {
    if ( window.deviceInfo.brand == 'ios' && window.deviceInfo.mode != 'webview' ) {
        window.deviceInfo.phonegap = false;
        complete();
    } else if ( window.deviceInfo.mobile ) {
        var timer = window.setInterval( function () {
            if ( window.device ) {
                window.deviceInfo.phonegap = true;
                complete();
            };
        }, 100 );
        window.setTimeout( function () { //failsafe
            if ( !window.device ) { //in webview, not in phonegap or phonegap failed
                window.clearInterval( timer );
                window.deviceInfo.phonegap = false;
                complete();
            };
        }, 5000 ); //fail after 5 seconds
    } else {
        window.deviceInfo.phonegap = false;
        complete();
    };
};
```

Comment: What a fantastic answer! This looks like exactly what I need :D

Answer (score 1):

We are developing an iPad app and deployed it as a mobile website too. Whenever PhoneGap specific calls are made, using a common method called isRunningOnPhoneGap() (returns false if the code is running as website) , we decide whether to invoke the PhoneGap feature or to display the web feature. This is how we decide if the app is running as a website or on a mobile device.

```
var isRunningOnPhoneGap: function () {

        if ((document.URL.indexOf('http://') === -1) && (document.URL.indexOf('https://') === -1)) {
            if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/)) {
                return true;
            } else {

                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Were you able to get this app approved through Apple?

Comment: This app is an enterprise app and it is not going through app store. I dont see any reason why apple would reject an app with this code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will work.I have tried the vice-versa of your requirement.Including the cordova js file works but with some functionalities not supported.But you will definitely get the basic ones.